# Restarting partially completed torrent with Transmission

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I have the following issue with transmission. I have a collection of files, which form part of a torrent, some of which are complete and some of which are incomplete (and have a .part extension). I want to resume the torrent, without losing the already downloaded data, so what I did was the following
- Downloaded the torrent file
- Shutdown transmission then replaced the contents of the directory with the files that I had already downloaded
- Restarted transmission and chose "Verify local data"

The problem is it recognizes that the complete files are finished and starts seeding. But the .part files it tries to restart from the beginning. Is there any way to overcome this?

One suggestion was to choose the option in transmission of not adding .part to incomplete files, then renaming all the existing incomplete files, but that seems kind of unwieldy.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Transmission, but a good client shouldn't be doing this. It should start downloading the remaining pieces of the incomplete files. Perhaps you can try with some other torrent program?

Comment: @karan Thanks, I may have to try a different program. I think "verify local data" might be discarding the incomplete data. However before I do the "verify local data" it doesn't even recognize the complete files.

Comment: No it won't, since according to its database those files haven't been completed yet. After all, you manually replaced them outside the program and so a recheck/verification would be required to tell it to update its database with the new file status.